# Получить путь до каталога выше

Tags: c#, wpf

В папке Debug имеется папка "Updater", из нее запускается exe и загружает файлы в папку bin/Debug/Updater/temp/, нужно переместить файлы из папки temp в папку /bin/
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить?

Answer (score 2):

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\"));
```

Вопрос решен